# In LISP is it possible to access a function's form?

Tags: functional-programming, lisp, common-lisp, sbcl, clisp

Suppose I define a function globally:

```
(defun x (y) (1+ y)) ;; Edit: my first example was too complicated
```

Is it possible to "coerce" the function x into a list like:

```
(x (y) (1+ y))
```

Thanks in advance!

PS - @Danlei's example works in Clozure CL with a special flag, however does anyone know how to get FUNCTION-LAMBDA-EXPRESSION to work in SBCL?

Comment: Your definition is flawed: x is a function and cannot be used with +

Comment: bandi: `x` is just a symbol.  In that context would refer to a variable.  (See danlei's example below.)

Comment: I added a possible (untested) solution for SBCL to my answer.

Comment: FUNCTION-LAMBDA-EXPRESSION works out of the box in CLISP..  I realize that some spec's in CL are interpreted differently and this case is one of them...

Comment: I found a similar thread here: http://www.lispforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=153

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try [FUNCTION-LAMBDA-EXPRESSION](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_fn_lam.htm):

```
(function-lambda-expression #'foo)
```

But it's not guaranteed to work ("… implementations are free to return ``nil, true, nil'' in all cases …").

For example in CCL:

```
CL-USER> (setq ccl:*save-definitions* t)
T
CL-USER> (defun x (x y) (+ x y))
X
CL-USER> (function-lambda-expression #'x)
(LAMBDA (X Y) (DECLARE (CCL::GLOBAL-FUNCTION-NAME X)) (BLOCK X (+ X Y)))
NIL
X
```

In SBCL, you might try `(setq sb-ext:*evaluator-mode* :interpret)` (untested). Maybe there are other ways to achieve this in SBCL (you might look for an analog of `*save-definitions*` or even try different `OPTIMIZE` settings), but I don't know about them. Beware that functions entered in the REPL won't be compiled after setting `*evaluator-mode*` to `:interpret`, so you will probably experience worse performance.

Comment: I found the reason why I couldn't get FUNCTION-LAMBDA-EXPRESSION to work in SBCL, apparently it is an optimization step not to save a copy of a function's sexp if it is not inline.  See https://bugs.launchpad.net/sbcl/+bug/560977

Comment: @ReubenPeter-Paul As a brief update, [a related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18650988/1281433) was asked recently, and it appears that newer releases of SBCL (see comments on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18652612/1281433)) have different behavior.

Answer (score 2):

In Common Lisp, you *might* be able to recover the definition of a function using `function-lambda-expression` (see the [HyperSpec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_fn_lam.htm)) or in some implementations `uncompile-function`.

Answer (score 0):

When I was spending time on a project to do significant function manipulation, it was easiest to do this sort of thing:

```
(defclass node ()
  (list-form
   compiled-obj))
```

First the list form consisting of '(lambda foo (x ) bar) would be assigned, then I would compile Foo and assign it to the compiled-ojb slot.